# Lead Information on an Activity Record

Tags: leads

Every time a lead is converted to a contact in Salesforce, I want an activity logged showing the lead has been converted - which I have set up. The other piece of information that I want to show on the activity record is the lead source. That way if a contact is a lead multiple times, I can see where that lead came from each time. I cannot fiure out how to put the lead source on the activity record easily. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add Lead Source as a custom text field on Activity, and then update that value in a trigger upon Lead conversion?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to workflow but you will not be able to get the field across.  Just trigger the workflow off something that is only in the lead object.

https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_workflow_tasks.htm

If you need that field to come across, then you will need to create a trigger.  Here is some information to get started if you have not done it before.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm